# Android-FTDI chip communicatrion

Tags: android, ftdi

I am a newbie in Android development, I want to establish a connection between an Android device and an FTDI chip (FT230X) so that the Android device can send data to a microcontroller via the FTDI chip. I already installed the D2xx library in Android Studio. Can anybody tell me how should I start with this FTDI stuff? How do I detect the FTDI chip from an Android app?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: And how does this connection look like? Where did you solder the chip?

Comment: @Mauker : yes , started with basic android programming. I am reading documentation provided by google. Also I started with USB device detection but no success.

Comment: @greenapps : I have one USB to serial communication module containing FTDI chip.( FT230x ,i know its vender and product id. ) first I want my app to detect FTDI chip module which is connected to tablet. FTDI Module have its own power supply.

Comment: 'i know its vender and product id.'. Any reason not to tell them? 'FTDI chip module which is connected to tablet'. How exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Late answer but hopefully future readers will find it useful.

Take a look at [FTDI's Android examples](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/SoftwareExamples/Android_Projects.htm).

Answer (score 0):

FTDI provide a driver to talk to their chips using the inbuilt Android USB Host API.  The driver is distributed as a .jar file that you would incorporate into your app.  There's a sample on their website showing how to use the driver.

[Android Java D2XX](http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/D2XX/Android_Java_D2xx.zip)